# USE EWS API to get meeting sensitivity data

Tags: exchangewebservices

We create a meeting from outlook, and set the meeting as private. But when use Exchange server API(EWS Managed API), we are not able to retrieve that information, the meeting is always set to “normal”, not “private”.
Is there any setting from Exchange Server prevent from reading a meeting’s sensibility property? or is there any requirement from API to get that setting?
Here is the sample code:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
const int NUM_APPTS = 15;

// Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
FolderId CalendarFolderIdVal = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "TrainingRoom@fmdemo.com");
CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, CalendarFolderIdVal, new PropertySet());

// Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

// Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
 cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End,AppointmentSchema.Sensitivity);

// Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
```

when looping through the appointments, even the meeting is private in outlook, it always reads as "normal".

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is happening because of the default setting on the Mailbox you are trying to retrieve the appointment from see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046(v=exchg.160).aspx

> the RemovePrivateProperty parameter specifies whether to clear the private flag for incoming meeting requests. Valid input for this parameter is $true or $false. The default value is $true.
>   By default, the private flag for incoming meeting requests is cleared. To ensure the private flag that was sent by the organizer in the original request remains as specified, set tthis parameter to $false.

Comment: Yes, "RemovePrivateProperty" setting solved the problem. Thanks! Glen